# Squared Dirichlet integral.

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform

I have a problem. I'm studing Fourier analysis and i saw a metode to calculate $\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}dx$ using Fourier transform but I'm asked to calculate $\int_0^{\infty}(\frac{\sin(x)}{x})^2dx$ . The general idea is to find a function, that has the Fourier transform exactly the function that I have to integrate and then to apply the inverse theorem or something else? Any tip on understanding the general method on integrating this kind of function using Fourier transform?

Also I would be happy to know if this is true for the Fourier series method. I saw that is possible to calculate the sum of the series $\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{1}{n^2}$. Using Fourier series, is it possible to calculate other interesting series? And what is the general method?

Comment: You can find $\int_0^\infty \sin^2(x)/x^2=\frac12\int_{-\infty}^\infty$ using the Plancherel Theorem.

Comment: Oh, thank but this dosen't solve the general case...

Comment: Use the convolution theorem for Fourier transforms: $F \{f(x)g(x) \} = F(s)*G(s)$, where $ f(x)=g(x)=\frac{\sin{x}}{x}$ in your case.

Comment: _What_ "general case"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Applying the inversion theorem, we may write

$$h(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{i\xi x}\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\frac{\sin(\xi)}{\xi} \mathrm{d}\xi$$
which leads to 
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\pi}\frac{\sin(\xi)}{\xi} \mathrm{d}\xi = h(0) = 1. $$
This in turn implies 
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(x)}{x} \mathrm{d}x = \frac{\pi}{2}$$

To calculate other integrals of other powers, it is sufficient to use Plancherel. The fourth power can be calculated in a similar fashion: 
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left(\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\frac{\sin(\xi)} {\xi}\right)^4 \mathrm{d}\xi =\|\hat{h}^2\|_{L^2}^2 = \frac{1}{2\pi} \|\widehat{h\ast h}\|_{L^2}^2 = \frac{1}{2\pi}\|h \ast h\|_{L^2}^2 = \frac{1}{2\pi}\frac{16}{3} $$
so we obtain

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin^4(x)}{x^4} \mathrm{d}x = \frac{\pi}{3}$$

This will hold also for other powers. I leave you the second power as an exercise.

Comment: Its not clear to me how is $h(x)$ and where dos it come from. And also, this metode works for cube power?

Comment: and why $h(0)=1$ ?

Comment: $h(x)$ is simply the name of the function I defined through the integral, it's like to say $f(x) = x^2$. 

$h(0) = 1$ because if you substitute $x = 0$ in the definition, you'll see it makes $1$.

Comment: i see just that $h(0)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\pi}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}dx$ from the definition.

Comment: Exactly.$$$$$$$$

Comment: ok but why that integral is $1$ ?

Comment: @HurjuiIonut About that question, I suggest you to search here on MSE site. Many people already asked for that question!

Comment: If we consider that as a known fact its ok!

Comment: @HurjuiIonut [Dirichlet Integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_integral)

Answer (score 0):

Introducing the Hurwitz-Zeta-Function
$$\zeta(s,q) := \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(q+n)^s}$$
we can rewrite for $a,b>1$
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(2 \pi x)^{a+b}}{x^b} \, \mathrm{d}x = \int_0^1 \sin(2 \pi x)^{a+b} \zeta(b,x) \, \mathrm{d}x.$$
This problem is equivalent to understand the Fourier series of the Hurwitz-Zeta-Function. A closed formula is given [here](http://functions.wolfram.com/ZetaFunctionsandPolylogarithms/Zeta2/06/03/01/01/0001/).